# How to solve "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException" while creating hive connection through pyhive in python?

Tags: python, hive, pyhive

> OperationalError: TExecuteStatementResp(status=TStatus(statusCode=3,
>   infoMessages=["*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error
>   while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:86 extraneous
>   input ';' expecting EOF near '':28:27",
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:324',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:148',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runInternal:SQLOperation.java:228',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:run:Operation.java:264',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementInternal:HiveSessionImpl.java:479',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatement:HiveSessionImpl.java:454',
>   'sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor136:invoke::-1',
>   'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43',
>   'java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:498',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:78',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:access$000:HiveSessionProxy.java:36',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1:run:HiveSessionProxy.java:63',
>   'java.security.AccessController:doPrivileged:AccessController.java:-2',
>   'javax.security.auth.Subject:doAs:Subject.java:422',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:doAs:UserGroupInformation.java:1869',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:59',
>   'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29:executeStatement::-1',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:executeStatement:CLIService.java:285',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:ExecuteStatement:ThriftCLIService.java:510',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1377',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1362',
>   'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39',
>   'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56',
>   'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:286',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617',
>   'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745',
>   "*org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException:line 1:86 extraneous
>   input ';' expecting EOF near '':33:6",
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver:parse:ParseDriver.java:222',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver:parse:ParseDriver.java:171',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compile:Driver.java:447',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compile:Driver.java:330',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compileInternal:Driver.java:1233',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compileAndRespond:Driver.java:1227',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:146'],
>   sqlState='42000', errorCode=40000, errorMessage="Error while compiling
>   statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:86 extraneous input ';'
>   expecting EOF near ''"), operationHandle=None)

Comment: there's an error in your query as indicated by the last several lines of your traceback, it would be more helpful to post the query at this point

Comment: Yes, issues in query where clause, working now, Thank you !! @gold_cy